# OnAppearing not called in prism xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I want a process to be called each time I navigated to my view to refresh a list.
I am using Xamarin Forms and prism framework.
I made my ViewModel derivate from ContentPage but the following method is never called :

```
 protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        //Do things
    }
```

How am I supposed to do to get the event? Is it better to use OnNavigateTo?

Answer (score 0):

Through the [document](https://prismlibrary.com/docs/xamarin-forms/page-lifecycle.html):

> There are times in your application where you may want to invoke code
> in your ViewModel based on when the Page Appears or Disappears without
> Navigation specific consideration. For these times you can utilize the
> **IPageLifecycleAware** interface to properly respond to the Appearing and
> Disappearing events from the Page.

```
public class ViewAViewModel : IPageLifecycleAware
{
    public void OnAppearing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We are appearing");
    }

    public void OnDisappearing()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("We are disappearing");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by without success?

Comment: I mean OnAppearing is not called even when my viewModel derivates from IPageLifecycleAware

Comment: There is a [sample project](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/tree/master/16-PageLifecycleAware) you can refer.

Comment: I just compared to my project, for me looks like I am doing the exact same thing: Autowire in the view, derivate from IPageLifecycleAware and call OnAppeating. Don t know what i am missing

Comment: It should work as it is written in the official documents. You can download that sample and check if it works. If it works, something must be missing in your project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224312/discussion-between-labelle-and-jack-hua-msft).

Comment: The code there is quite simple and can you check if you are using the same version of Prism ? Or is the ViewModel you using corresponding the right view?

Comment: If my answer helps you, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to make my code work, I add to do this in my code behind from the page:

```
  protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        (BindingContext as IPageLifecycleAware)?.OnAppearing();
    }
```

Still a mystery why I need to add this and it is not in the sample.

Comment: Please call `base.OnAppearing();` in `OnAppearing()`.

Comment: There is no base.OnAppearing() accessible

Comment: Is this OnAppearing() method override in ContentPage? It should have.

Comment: In witch content Page? In fact my VM is declared as followed: ```public class PlantGroupListViewModel : BindableBase, IPageLifecycleAware```

Comment: If the OnAppearing method is in the VM, it should not have override keyword. See sample [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism-Samples-Forms/blob/master/16-PageLifecycleAware/src/PrismSample/ViewModels/ViewAViewModel.cs).

Answer (score 0):

at the time of this post, the sample does it differently. It uses Behaviors to achieve expectation

It has a **PageLifeCycleAwareBehavior** class

```
private void OnAppearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MvvmHelpers.InvokeViewAndViewModelAction<IPageLifecycleAware>(AssociatedObject, aware => aware.OnAppearing());
}

private void OnDisappearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MvvmHelpers.InvokeViewAndViewModelAction<IPageLifecycleAware>(AssociatedObject, aware => aware.OnDisappearing());
}
```

You can see the full implementation [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism.Maui/blob/master/src/Prism.Maui/Behaviors/PageLifeCycleAwareBehavior.cs)

You can also call **Initialize** is a good alternative

Add ini to your class

```
public class HelloViewModel : BindableBase, IInitialize
```

then add the following method

```
public void Initialize(INavigationParameters parameters)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```